# add g++ to heroku node server

Tags: heroku, g++

I'm trying to run g++ command on heroku but get this error :

2020-07-25T16:27:31.627497+00:00 app[web.1]: make: g++: Command not found
2020-07-25T16:27:31.627498+00:00 app[web.1]: make: *** [build/analyzerinfo.o] Error 127

how can I install g++ on heroku?

Comment: What's your use case? Why are you trying to compile C++ code at runtime?

Comment: I'm trying to use cppcheck on my server I can build it easily on my local machine but on heroku I get an error

Comment: And what language is your app built in? Worded differently: what buildpack is your app using?

Comment: I'm using Node JS

Comment: Please see [this answer I just wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204841/354577) on a similar question "How to install SVN at heroku?"

Comment: In my case Do I also need to only write `subversion` in the Aptfile?

Comment: No, you need to list the Ubuntu packages you want in your `Aptfile`. In your case that's probably `g++` and maybe some other things as well (I don't think the buildpack resolves dependencies).

Comment: I think what's wrong is that The `make` command is not installed on heroku, any quick tips on that?, Thanks for taking the time to support me newbie :)

Comment: ...it's exactly the same answer as before. Just list all the packages you need, e.g. `make` and `g++`, one on each line, in your `Aptfile`.

Comment: it doesn't look like it's making any changes to to heroku app , Do i need to do anything else for heroku to take the Aptfile into account?

Comment: Did you read that whole answer and set up both buildpacks?