# How to install SVN at heroku?

Tags: heroku, svn

I have a project that needs SVN to install some packages. Specifically, I depend on [`node-steam-resources`](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam-resources) and its installation instructions say

> Run `npm install seishun/node-steam-resources`. It fetches the Steam resources and requires `svn`.

On localhost it works after installing SVN console.

But how to do the same on Heroku?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is Subversion required at build time or at runtime? Specifically, what are you installing? And how?

Comment: Subversion is required at build time to install steam-resources module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [the `apt` buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install OS-level packages [in addition to your existing buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) (presumably `heroku/nodejs`).

1. Create a new file called `Aptfile` in the root of your repository. This is where you will define any additional Ubuntu packages you require.
2. Edit that file so it looks like this:

   ```
   subversion
   ```
3. Add and commit that file.
4. Configure your Heroku app to use the correct buildpacks:

   1. First, set your Node.js buildpack explicitly:

      ```
      heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
      ```
   2. Then add the `apt` buildpack:

      ```
      heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
      ```
   3. Run `heroku buildpacks` to make sure you see both buildpacks, with the `apt` buildpack showing up first and the Node.js buildpack showing up second.
5. Finally, redeploy your application and watch the build output. You should see the `subversion` package get installed, then your Node.js dependencies get installed.